# how can i change auto increment by looping to start from 1 after month change or empty database

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have tried to reset a var $potong to start from 1 again when `date = '01'` and database table is empty.

Here is my code :

```
$month = date('n');
$b=romanNumerals($month);
$years=date('Y');
echo"<div class='form-group'>";
$tanggal=date('d'); 
$s=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM preorder ORDER BY id_po DESC LIMIT 1');

while($a=mysql_fetch_array($s)){
    $nomor = $a[2];
    $potong = (int)substr($nomor,0,3);
    $potong++;
    $awal =1;
}

$kosong= mysql_num_rows($s);
if($potong == 0 || $tanggal == 01){
    echo"<input type='text' class='form-control input-lg' placeholder='' name='no_po' Readonly = true value='".sprintf('%03s',$awal)."/$b/CMT/$years'>";
}
else{   
    echo"<input type='text' class='form-control input-lg' placeholder='' name='no_po' Readonly = true value='".sprintf('%03s',$potong)."/$b/CMT/$years'>";
}
```

I need suggestions, how to I can create this condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you answer the bolded questions above in your question?

Comment: umm ,  i didnt type that , i wil edit it

Answer (score 0):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is meant for use with keys. If you want a value to start over, you will have to keep track yourself. If you have a really specific table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column set as key for *month* only:

```
CREATE TABLE myMonth(
month_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then you could use the modulus/remainder:

```
month=month_id%12+1;
```

Which will return the month for you (the +1 is to correct for the fact that the modulus will remainder of `value-ROUND_DOWN(value/12)*12`, which will be zero if the value is a multiple of 12, and a calendar has 1 as the first month (Pretty much except in Java where somebody decided that 0 was a nice number of month))

Comment: so if i want to get a value start from  1 again  when date of month start in 01 the code be like : 'create table myDate( date_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRiMARY KEY); date=date_id%30+1; value-ROUND_DOWN(value/30)*30' is it like this ?

Comment: Yes, but with months with 28/29/30/31 days, that will fail horribly. So my example was more for the really exotic case you would like to do this with a month. What you better can look at is the mysql date time functions.

Comment: ohh, okayy 
thanks anyway
i hope you can give me some example lol , jk